# ComboBox Item Selection With Unknown ItemIndex

Tags: delphi

I am very much a novice to Delphi. I have a Delphi XE2 Program. I am creating **`ComboBox1`** during form creation as follows:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ComboBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  ComboBox1.Items.Clear;
  ComboBox1.Items.Add('BBBB');
  ComboBox1.Items.Add('DDDD');
  ComboBox1.Items.Add('AAAA');
  ComboBox1.Items.Add('CCCC');
  ComboBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
end;
```

...and here are the **`ComboBox1`** properties:

```
Sorted = True
OnChange = ComboBox1Change
OnDropDown = ComboBox1DropDown
```

My requirement is to do some job upon selection of items, using **`case of`**, keeping in mind that I don't know the **`ItemIndex`** of **AAAA ...... DDDD** etc.

So I have tried the following:

```
case ComboBox1.ItemIndex of ComboBox1.Items.IndexOf('AAAA'):
  begin
    //
    //
  end
end;

case ComboBox1.ItemIndex of ComboBox1.Items.IndexOf('BBBB'):
  begin
    //
    //
  end
end;

case ComboBox1.ItemIndex of ComboBox1.Items.IndexOf('CCCC'):
  begin
    //
    //
  end
end;

case ComboBox1.ItemIndex of ComboBox1.Items.IndexOf('DDDD'):
  begin
    //
    //
  end
end;
```

My Project is not compiling. It is giving an error as follows:

```
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(....): E2026 Constant expression expected
```

Another question is: what is the difference between `//` and `{}` in Delphi? Basically can I write any comment for understanding my program by using both `//` and `{}`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`case` only works with ordinal (integer) types and constant expressions. Use several `if` statements instead.

```
var
  SelectedItem: string;

begin
  SelectedItem := '';
  if ComboBox1.ItemIndex <> -1 then
    SelectedItem := ComboBox1.Items[ComboBox1.ItemIndex];

  // Or you can just exit if ComboBox1.ItemIndex is -1
  // If ComboBox1.ItemIndex = -1 then
  //   Exit;
  if SelectedItem = 'AAAA' then
  begin

  end
  else if SelectedItem = 'BBBB' then
  begin

  end
  else if SelectedItem = 'CCCC' then
  begin

  end
  else if SelectedItem = 'DDDD' then
  begin

  end;
end;
```

As far as the difference between `{}` and `//`, the first can wrap multiple line comments, while the second is a single line comment only.

```
{ 
  This is a multiple line comment
  between curly braces.
}

// This is a single line comment. If I want to exend it
// to a second line, I need another single line comment
```

There is also another multiple line comment indicator as well, carried over from the old Pascal days:

```
(*
  This is also a multiple line comment
  in Delphi.
  {
  It is useful to surround blocks of code that
  contains other comments already.
  }
  This is still a comment here.
*)
```

Comment: What will be the value of `SelectedItem` when no item is selected?

Comment: You have to test for that first. I'll edit to show that as well.